# How to compute a new variable in an efficient way using R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 900 observations and 121 columns.

I have to calculate a new column.

The new column is the result of multiplying and adding several columns. The columns follow a pattern. Something like:

```
newcolumn= (C42*C82)+(C43*C83)+(C44*C84)+.....(C81*C121).
```

How can I do this in a more efficient way than just entering the whole formula as above?

Comment: Make a small example dataframe. Then use `dput()` on it to get a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to partition, say, matrix `A` (forgetting the first 41 columns, in your case) in your head into two relevant parts, `A1` and `A2`. Then one can see that this new column is a vector of row sums of a column-wise multiplication `A1 * A2`. Hence, e.g.,

```
rowSums(M[, 42:81] * M[, 82:121])
```

gives the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with matrix multiplication (the inner product or dot product in this case) of the values in columns 42 to 81 with the values in columns 82 to 121, by row. In R, `%*%` is the matrix multiplication operator. Here's an example with fake data.

```
# Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = as.data.frame(replicate(121, rnorm(5)))

dat$new = apply(dat, 1, function(x) x[42:81] %*% x[82:121])
```

Comment: You might have mentioned that `%*%` is matrix multiplication.

Comment: The inner product is the matrix operation, but I'll make it more explicit.

Answer (score -1):

Less elegant than the other answer, but here's a way to resolve your problem using some loops:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {     #for each row in the dataframe
  numtest <- 0              #re-initialize your placeholder sum at each row
  for (j in 42:81) {        #for each "multiplied" group that you want to sum up
    numtest <- numtest + (df[i,j] * df[i, j+40])  #add to your placeholder
  }
  df[i, 122] <- numtest     #fill in col 122 with final generated sum.
}
```